# auto with const_cast reference behaves strange

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, auto, const-cast

Can anyone help me to understand this "weird" behavior? I was playing around with c++11 after long pause in c++ programming. Why everything works fine until I use auto?

```
static void printIt(int a,const int *b, const int &c)
{
     std::cout << "\nArg1 : " << a << "\nArg2 : " << *b << "\nArg3 : " << c 
     << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int myVar { 0x01 };
    const int *pmV { &myVar };
    const int &rmV { myVar };

    printIt(myVar,pmV,rmV); //OK prints 1,1,1

    *(const_cast<int *>(pmV)) = 0x02;   //Remove constness from pmV and sets new value
    printIt(myVar,pmV,rmV); //OK prints 2,2,2

    (const_cast<int &>(rmV)) = 0x03;    //Remove constness from rmV and sets new value
    printIt(myVar,pmV,rmV); //OK prints 3,3,3

    myVar = 0x04;
    printIt(myVar,pmV,rmV); //OK prints 4,4,4

    //So far so good...

    auto a = const_cast<int *>(pmV);    //Creates a new variable of type int *
    *a = 0x05;
    printIt(myVar,a,rmV); //OK prints 5,5,5

    auto b = const_cast<int &>(rmV);    //Should have the same effect as (const_cast<int &>(rmV)), right???
    b = 0x06;
    printIt(myVar,a,b); //WRONG!!! prints 5,5,6
}
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks so much.

Comment: `auto` is not a reference type, `auto &` is.

Comment: You want `auto &b =`.